# CSS - how to target all elements within first instance of class?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I am trying to target the **rect** element within **the first** g element with class "v-datapoint v-morphable-datapoint" - so I want to highlight only **rect element 1**. See my CSS code below:

```
<g class="v-datapoint-group">
    <g>
        <g class="v-datapoint v-morphable-datapoint">First</g>
            <rect>1</rect>
        <g class="v-datapoint v-morphable-datapoint">Second</g>
            <rect>2</rect>
        <g class="v-datapoint v-morphable-datapoint">Third</g>
    </g>
</g>
```

Can anyone please help how to do it properly? I have tried the following:

```
g.v-datapoint-group g.v-datapoint.v-morphable-datapoint  {
    background-color:yellow;
} /* highlights word First, Second, Third */

g.v-datapoint-group g.v-datapoint.v-morphable-datapoint rect {
    background-color: yellow;
} /* doesn't do anything */

g.v-datapoint-group g.v-datapoint.v-morphable-datapoint:first-child {
    background-color: yellow;
} /* highlights word First */

g.v-datapoint-group g.v-datapoint.v-morphable-datapoint:first-child rect {
    background-color: yellow;
} /* doesn't do anything */

g.v-datapoint-group rect {
    background-color: yellow;
} /* highlights both 1 & 2 */

g.v-datapoint-group rect:first-child {
    background-color: yellow;
} /* doesn't do anything */
```

Any ideas how to target rect element 1?

Thanks,
Agata

Comment: Try using `!important`

Comment: @TricksfortheWeb !important should be avoided at all costs.

Comment: Isn't necessary anyway...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
g.v-datapoint.v-morphable-datapoint:first-child {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

**EDIT**

If you want just the rect under the first G, add this information:

```
g.v-datapoint.v-morphable-datapoint:first-child + rect {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

Comment: No problem! If you would kindly vote as the answer, I would appreciate! ^^

Comment: Sorry. I can't simulate your code that you put in your image. I guess its not enough, nothing appears. Try putting it in a fiddle, or sending the full code.

Answer (score 0):

Try `g.v-datapoint-group g.v-datapoint.v-morphable-datapoint:nth-of-type(1) + rect`. This should select all sibling `rect`s of the first data point.